# How to convert multiple column foreign keys in the same way

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have a table `relationship`:

```
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| playerid1 | playerid2 | relationship |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
|         1 |         3 | friend       |
|         1 |         2 | enemy        |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

and another table `player`:

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Hattie |
|  2 | Jazz   |
|  3 | Ben    |
+----+--------+
```

I want to return all players who are enemies like `'Hattie', 'Jazz'`

The best I have is:

```sql
select 
  player1.name, 
  player2.name 
from 
  (
    select 
      player.name 
    from 
      player, 
      relationship r 
    where 
      r.relationship = 'enemy' 
      and player.id = r.playerid1
  ) player1, 
  (
    select 
      player.name 
    from 
      relationship r, 
      player 
    where 
      r.relationship = 'enemy' 
      and player.id = r.playerid2
  ) player2;
```

This is so long! And there is logical duplication for each player.

Is there a way to do it shorter?

I can of course `select playerid1, playerid2 from relationship where relationship = 'enemy';` to get the ids in two columns, so I'm really suspecting there must be a more graceful column-wise foreign key reference lookup than what I manually created above.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the player table twice

```
SELECT 
   p1.name,p2.name
FROM
relationship rl JOIN player p1 ON r.playerid1  = p1.id
JOIN player p2 ON r.playerid2  = p2.id
WHERE r.relationship = 'enemy'
```